# This working copy's repository URL shorthand in SVN?

Tags: svn

When the current working directory is an SVN working copy, I can use '^' as a shorthand for the repository URL.

Is there also a nice shorthand for the URL of the working copy such that `svn list <???>/../` does not address the parent directory of the working copy, but the parent directory of the working copy inside the repository. What would be the shortcut to put in for `<???>` if any?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be such a shortcut. As a workaround I came up with this bash function:

```
function svnurls() {
  svn info &>/dev/null || return
  local d=$(svn info | sed -n -e '/^URL/s/.*: //p')
  local i=0
  while ! [[ "$d" =~ ^[^:]*:/$ ]]; do
    echo $i $d
    typeset -g svn$i="${d}"
    d=${d%/*}
    i=$((i+1))
  done
}
```

It first checks whether it is called in an svn working copy and returns immediately if it is not.

If it is, it greps the working copy's repository url from `svn info` and provides it as well as all its ancestors in the shell variables `svn0`, `svn1` and so on. In addition, the ancestor urls are printed on the command line for easy reference in subsequent commands, which can be things like:

```
svn list $svn1  # list repository parents of working copy
svn switch $svn1/branches/mybranch # assuming standard layout and trunk checkout
```

(Hint: the syntax `^/branches` does not work in multi-project repositories where trunk and branches and tags can be deeper down in the hierarchy).